How to create an environment-aware configuration in Laravel 11?
I'm working on a Laravel 11 project and I need to set up environment-aware configurations that is accessible with config method. For example, I have a constant.php file in the config directory for general configurations, and a constant.php file in the config/production directory for production-specific configurations.
Here's the directory structure:
config/
    constant.php
config/production/
    constant.php

I want to achieve the following:
config('constant')
On local and staging environments, load only the config/constant.php.
On production environment, load both config/constant.php and config/production/constant.php, with config/production/constant.php overriding any overlapping configurations from config/constant.php.
How can I configure Laravel 11 to achieve this environment-aware configuration loading?
Code samples or any specific methods would be greatly appreciated!
Additional context:
I'm familiar with Laravel's env() function and configuration caching, but I'm not sure how to implement this selective configuration loading based on the environment.

@Mr.Kenneth it should works with the laravel config config repository so that it should also change/update the vendor specific access to config.

The general idea is you create a different .env file for each environment and use env(..) to read from that file (which will be different from each environment) instead of creating a separate .php config file for each environment.

Isn't that what the .env file is for? How is this different from using .env files? Do you have a specific case where .env files won't work?

@apokryfos I understand the typical approach of using different .env files for each environment and leveraging the env() function to access environment-specific settings. However, in my case, the configuration data is more complex and involves nested arrays and other structures that are cumbersome to manage using environment variables alone. By using PHP configuration files, I can take advantage of the full expressive power of PHP to define complex configurations and easily override specific settings in a hierarchical manner.

@brombeer Indeed, .env files are designed for environment-specific settings, but they primarily handle simple key-value pairs. My situation involves configurations that go beyond simple environment variables, including nested arrays and more complex structures. For instance, I might have a large configuration array in config/constant.php that defines default values, and I want to override only specific parts of this array in config/production/constant.php for the production environment.

Ohk,I solved it :) To create environment-aware configurations in Laravel 11, you can extend the configuration repository in your AppServiceProvider. This method dynamically merges environment-specific configurations with the general configurations based on the current environment.
$this->app->extend('config', function (\Illuminate\Contracts\Config\Repository $configRepository) {
  $environment = $this->app->environment();
  $envConfigPath = config_path($environment);

  if (is_dir($envConfigPath)) {
    $finder = new \Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder();
    $finder->files()->name('*.php')->in($envConfigPath);

    foreach ($finder as $file) {
      $filename = $file->getBasename('.php');
      $generalConfig = $configRepository->get($filename, []);
      $envConfig = require $file->getRealPath();
      
      $mergedConfig = array_merge($generalConfig, $envConfig);
      $configRepository->set($filename, $mergedConfig);
    }
  }

  return $configRepository;
});


This code might be simpler to what you currently are using:
Add this in any service provider register function:
public function register() {
        parent::register();
        if (!File::exists(Application::getInstance()->getCachedConfigPath())) {
            $environment = $this->app->environment();
            $envConstants = config($environment.'.constant', []);
            config([
                'constant' => array_merge(
                    config('constant'),
                    $envConstants
                )
            ]);
        }
    }

All your constants should be available using config('constant.constantname')
The if !File::exists(Application::getInstance()->getCachedConfigPath())) is there because if the config is cached then this provider would have ran before caching and the config change would already be there (so there's no need to run it again)

its good, but what if there are multiple files?

You'd still need to loop through the files.
